# Accessing local file system is not allowed in oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I followed this instruction to install oozie 4.3.1 on hadoop 2.6.5 and ubuntu 16.04 with oracle java 1.8.0. https://www.iamjrp.com/2017/installing-oozie/                                                       I have 3  hadoop nodes one master and two slaves.   I used this example to test my installation :https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.0/DG_Examples.html
and work flow does not started because of  this error:
2018-04-29 17:11:41,646  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[hadoopmaster] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[shell-wf] JOB[0000000-180429171130920-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-180429171130920-oozie-hdus-W@shell-node] Error starting action [shell-node]. ErrorType [ERROR], ErrorCode [UnsupportedOperationException], Message [UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:446)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1204)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1386)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:234)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:65)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:287)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:332)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:261)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Accessing local file system is not allowed
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.initialize(RawLocalFileSystem.java:48)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.initialize(LocalFileSystem.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.updateShareLib(ShareLibService.java:554)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getShareLibJars(ShareLibService.java:366)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getSystemLibJars(ShareLibService.java:432)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addSystemShareLibForAction(JavaActionExecutor.java:756)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addAllShareLibs(JavaActionExecutor.java:853)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.setLibFilesArchives(JavaActionExecutor.java:844)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1095)
    ... 11 more
2018-04-29 17:11:41,648  WARN ActionStartXCommand:523 - SERVER[hadoopmaster] USER[hduser] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[shell-wf] JOB[0000000-180429171130920-oozie-hdus-W] ACTION[0000000-180429171130920-oozie-hdus-W@shell-node] Setting Action Status to [DONE]

thanks for your help !

Comment: Well, Oozie is designed to run on multiple machines via YARN tasks. You cannot access the local filesystem... What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you able to provide your workflow.xml and an example of the properties being passed? 

Your shell script is going to be ran within a container that could be spawned on one of a number of nodes within your cluster. If you are just trying to read a local file one approach here is to store it on HDFS and then provide a copy to the Oozie Shell Action instance using the <file> tag.

What I'm seeing above is a little too generic for me to get a chance at understanding what is going on.

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited can these correction help you to help me ?thank you !

Comment: @AnthonyK I edited can these correction help you to help me ?thank you !

Comment: Based on `at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.initialize`... You've configured Hadoop not to use `hdfs://` address but `file://` or Oozie is not picking up your core-site.xml. Please edit your question to include the workflow you're running and your Hadoop configuration files